# How do I download a dataset from the Humanitarian Data Exchange (HDX) using the HDX Python API library?

Tags: python, dataset, cycle, hdx

I don't quite understand how I can download data from a dataset. I only download one file, and there are several of them. How can I solve this problem?

I am using hdx API library. There is a small example in the documentation. A list is returned to me and I use the download method, but only the first file from the list is downloaded, not all of them.

My code:

```
from hdx.hdx_configuration import Configuration
from hdx.data.dataset import Dataset

Configuration.create(hdx_site='prod', user_agent='A_Quick_Example', hdx_read_only=True)
dataset = Dataset.read_from_hdx('novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases')
resources = dataset.get_resources()
print(resources)
url, path = resources[0].download()
print('Resource URL %s downloaded to %s' % (url, path))
```

I tried to use different methods, but only this one turned out to be working, it seems some kind of error in the loop, but I do not understand how to solve it.

Result

> Resource URL https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/api/data-preview.csv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv&filename=time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv downloaded to C:\Users\tred1\AppData\Local\Temp\time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv.CSV

Forgot to add that I get a list of strings where there is a download URL value. Probably the problem is in the loop.

When I use a for-loop I get this:

```
  for res in resources:
        print(res)
        res[0].download()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tred1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/HDXapi.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/tred1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/HDXapi.py", line 21, in main
    res[0].download()
  File "C:\Users\tred1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 1010, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 0
```

[image]

Datasets

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the download link as follows:

```
dataset = Dataset.read_from_hdx('acled-conflict-data-for-africa-1997-lastyear')
lita_resources = dataset.get_resources()

dictio=lista_resources[1]
url=dictio['download_url']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the following code which downloads each resource in the dataset from HDX and displays the url that was downloaded along with the path to which the file was downloaded.

```
from hdx.api.configuration import Configuration
from hdx.data.dataset import Dataset

Configuration.create(hdx_site="prod", user_agent="A_Quick_Example", hdx_read_only=True)
dataset = Dataset.read_from_hdx("novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases")
resources = dataset.get_resources()
for res in resources:
    url, path = res.download()
    print(f"Resource URL {url} downloaded to {path}")
```

You can supply a folder to which to download by using `res.download("FOLDER")`.